# How to make \ell from XITS-math less slanted

Tags: unicode-math, times, stix

I find the `\ell` symbol too slanted with `XITS-math`.

[image]

Is there a "proper" way to get it a bit "less" slanted (I find it could be confused with a caligraphic C)?

MWE (my engine is luatex):

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[%
  Extension = .otf,
  BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
  Ligatures=TeX,
]{XITSMath-Regular}

\begin{document}

$\ell$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can newly load the font with an artificial negative slant just for the glyph you need.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[
  Extension = .otf,
  BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
  Ligatures=TeX,
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[
  Extension = .otf,
  BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
  Ligatures=TeX,
  FakeSlant=-0.25,
  range=\ell,
]

\begin{document}

$\ell$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the glyph next to an *x*, with the setting above.

[image]

Here is the output with no adjustment.

[image]

You see that the *x* hasn't changed. On the other hand, why would you want `\ell`?